# How does this work? (Nested for loop)

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I don't understand why this returns 55? Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.
This code snippet is taken from "Professional JavaScript for Web developers". I have understood most of the book thus far but struggled slightly with this concept. I want to be clear on it before moving on. It is simply for my understanding.

```
var num = 0;
outermost: 
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
 for (var j=0; j <10; j++) {
    if (i == 5 && j == 5) {
        break outermost;
    }
    num++;
 }
}
alert(num);
```

Comment: `5 (outer iterations) * 10 (inner iterations) + 5 (inner iterations before it breaks) = 55`

Comment: What result were you expecting?

Comment: I was just enquiring as to why it was 55, I wasn't expecting anything different.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I'm sure this is homework. :P

Comment: No this is a code snippet from "Professional JavaScript for Web Developers". I didn't understand the explanation in the book and sought a better explanation.

Comment: @JoshuaPP - If this is a homework, you should put aside your computer, take out a sheet of paper, and go through the whole loop by writing down and keeping track the values. At least this is what I had to do in my CS course. Using `console.log` is not helpful at all because all you see is the program outputting a bunch of useless values.

Comment: Why has my question been downvoted? I wish to avoid this in the future but I need to know why first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below, I've added some trace debugging to help you see what's going on:

```
var num = 0;
outermost: 
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log('outermost: {i:'+i+', num:'+num+'}');
 for (var j=0; j <10; j++) {
     console.log('innermost: {i:'+i+', j:'+j+', num:'+num+'}');
    if (i == 5 && j == 5) {
        break outermost;
    }
    num++;
 }
}
alert(num);
```

Here's the console output:

```
outermost: {i:0, num:0}
innermost: {i:0, j:0, num:0}
innermost: {i:0, j:1, num:1}
innermost: {i:0, j:2, num:2}
innermost: {i:0, j:3, num:3}
innermost: {i:0, j:4, num:4}
innermost: {i:0, j:5, num:5}
innermost: {i:0, j:6, num:6}
innermost: {i:0, j:7, num:7}
innermost: {i:0, j:8, num:8}
innermost: {i:0, j:9, num:9}
outermost: {i:1, num:10}
innermost: {i:1, j:0, num:10}
innermost: {i:1, j:1, num:11}
innermost: {i:1, j:2, num:12}
innermost: {i:1, j:3, num:13}
innermost: {i:1, j:4, num:14}
innermost: {i:1, j:5, num:15}
innermost: {i:1, j:6, num:16}
innermost: {i:1, j:7, num:17}
innermost: {i:1, j:8, num:18}
innermost: {i:1, j:9, num:19}
outermost: {i:2, num:20}
innermost: {i:2, j:0, num:20}
innermost: {i:2, j:1, num:21}
innermost: {i:2, j:2, num:22}
innermost: {i:2, j:3, num:23}
innermost: {i:2, j:4, num:24}
innermost: {i:2, j:5, num:25}
innermost: {i:2, j:6, num:26}
innermost: {i:2, j:7, num:27}
innermost: {i:2, j:8, num:28}
innermost: {i:2, j:9, num:29}
outermost: {i:3, num:30}
innermost: {i:3, j:0, num:30}
innermost: {i:3, j:1, num:31}
innermost: {i:3, j:2, num:32}
innermost: {i:3, j:3, num:33}
innermost: {i:3, j:4, num:34}
innermost: {i:3, j:5, num:35}
innermost: {i:3, j:6, num:36}
innermost: {i:3, j:7, num:37}
innermost: {i:3, j:8, num:38}
innermost: {i:3, j:9, num:39}
outermost: {i:4, num:40}
innermost: {i:4, j:0, num:40}
innermost: {i:4, j:1, num:41}
innermost: {i:4, j:2, num:42}
innermost: {i:4, j:3, num:43}
innermost: {i:4, j:4, num:44}
innermost: {i:4, j:5, num:45}
innermost: {i:4, j:6, num:46}
innermost: {i:4, j:7, num:47}
innermost: {i:4, j:8, num:48}
innermost: {i:4, j:9, num:49}
outermost: {i:5, num:50}
innermost: {i:5, j:0, num:50}
innermost: {i:5, j:1, num:51}
innermost: {i:5, j:2, num:52}
innermost: {i:5, j:3, num:53}
innermost: {i:5, j:4, num:54}
innermost: {i:5, j:5, num:55}
```

As you can see, the inner loop executes the full 10 times until `i` becomes 5, then the inner loop executes 5 more times.

Comment: Thank you very much. That makes complete sense now. Trace debugging? I will have to figure out how to see that myself. I am currently just typing in each of the books examples into chrome dev tools.

Comment: In Chrome, you can open the menu, choose Tools, and then JavaScript console to find the console (or just press Ctrl+Shift+J). Any calls to `console.log` will be displayed there. Other browsers have similar features (some older browsers do not understand `console.log`, but all newer mainstream browsers do). See also [Software tracing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_(software)#Software_tracing).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to understand what is happening here is to display some info while it is happening, like so :

```
var num = 0;
outermost: 
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log('i = ' + i);
 for (var j=0; j <10; j++) {
    console.log('j = ' + j);
    if (i == 5 && j == 5) {
        break outermost;
    }
    num++;
    console.log('num = ' + num);
 }
}
alert(num);
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/e72b3/)

Comment: Made a small change to your demo to make it a little easier to read: http://jsfiddle.net/e72b3/1/